# Angularjs Doesn't send parameter value in $http get request to API(Sets to null in API)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have created a below factory which is supposed to return some data based by taking url and an input paramenter as No.

```html
(function () {
    'use strict'
    angular.module('MainApp').factory('GetData', ['$http', function ($http) {
        return {
            getCountries: function (url, No) {
                return $http({
                    method: "GET",
                    url: url,
                    DNo: No,
                    
                });
            }
        }

    }]);
})();

I have injected this factory to my controller and used as below.

GetData.getCountries('/General/API/GetDetails', $scope.No).then(function (res) {
                   
                    console.log(res.data);
                }, function (res) {

                });

            }

and here is my API.

 public JsonResult GetDetails(string DNo)
        {
            var allCntry = entity.spGetCountries(DNo).ToList();

            return Json(allCntry, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

All is good, the factory calls the api but does not send the parameter value, my API always set/initialized to null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply search parameters to a URL with the $http service, use the `params` property of the config:

```
angular.module('MainApp').factory('GetData', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getCountries: function (url, No) {
            return $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: url,
                //DNo: No,
                //USE params property
                params: { Dno: No }

            });
        }
    }

}]);
```

> config 
>   - **params** – `{Object.<string|Object>}` – Map of strings or objects which will be serialized with the `paramSerializer` and appended as GET parameters.
>
> [-- AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Usage.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage)